# Why does every 3-string, composed of two letters have exactly 3 palindromic substrings?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, palindrome

Why does every 3-string, composed of two letters have exactly 3 palindromic substrings?

for example:
aab has a, b and aa
aba has a,b and aba

I have been doing some practice questions for an upcoming Maths Challenge. There's one question I can't seem to grasp. I'm not sure entirely sure where to start. I don't know how to approach this one.. any help would be appreciated

Comment: A $3$-string is a string of $3$ letters?

Comment: a three string consists of 2 letters and is 3 'digits' long

Comment: Other than the 'aaa','bbb', every 3-string has at least one 'a' and one 'b'. In those cases: Every 3-string contains at least 2, namely 'a' and 'b' themselves. If the third letter in the 3-string connects in a *consecutive* way (either 'aa' or 'bb'), we have exactly one more example (the string itself isn't palindromic). Otherwise, if the third letter does not connect in a *consecutive* way, we have exactly one more example (the string itself is now palindromic) because the alternating 2-substrings are not palindromic. In all cases, we must have exactly 3 (distinct) palindromic substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only $2^3=8$ cases to check. The question also implies *distinct* palindromes, otherwise there would be more than $3$ of them in some strings:
$$aaa\to a,aa,aaa$$
$$aab\to a,aa,b$$
$$aba\to a,b,aba$$
$$abb\to a,b,bb$$
$$baa\to b,a,aa$$
$$bab\to a,b,bab$$
$$bba\to b,bb,a$$
$$bbb\to b,bb,bbb$$

Comment: But why is this the case. Why do all 3-strings have 3 distinct palindromes?

Comment: @AandreaJordan I enumerated all possible cases, so it is true.

Comment: I understand it is true, but the question more so is why is this the case.

Comment: @AandreaJordan There is no "why". It is more of an "it just is" question.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @AandreaJordan And thank you too. You are the last link in the chain... because of your upvote and accept, I have earned the Legendary badge.